# save listview data to same excel file but different sheet

Tags: .net

i already know how to save in excel using openfiledialog. but what i want to happen is that when i save another file, i want it to be saved in my existing file but in a different sheet. can you guys help me?

this is my code for saving

```
Public Sub saveExcelFile(ByVal FileName As String)
            Dim xls As New Excel.Application
            Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet
            Dim i As Integer
            xls.Workbooks.Add()
            sheet = xls.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
            Dim row As Integer = 1
            Dim col As Integer = 1
            For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
                    For i = 0 To item.SubItems.Count - 1
                            sheet.Cells(row, col) = item.SubItems(i).Text
                            col = col + 1
                    Next
                    row += 1
                    col = 1
            Next
            xls.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(FileName)
            xls.Workbooks.Close()
            xls.Quit()
    End Sub


Private Sub btnsave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsave.Click
            Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel File|*.xlsx"
            saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save an Excel File"
            saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
            If saveFileDialog1.FileName <> "" Then
                    saveExcelFile(saveFileDialog1.FileName)
            End If
            MessageBox.Show("Record Saved!")
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) for exporting to excel. You can specify Work sheet using NPOI. See the [documentation](http://npoi.codeplex.com/documentation) for more details

You can also use [Officehelper](http://officehelper.codeplex.com/documentation)

**Edit:**

Use this sample code for creating excel sheet using NPOI. It is only a sample code. You need to refer the documentation for more details.

```
List<OrderViewModel> orderViewModelList = SelectOrders();

            //Add Column title
            HSSFWorkbook hssfworkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet sheet1 = hssfworkbook.CreateSheet("Sheet1");
            sheet1.CreateRow(0).CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Order No");

            sheet1.CreateRow(0).CreateCell(5).SetCellValue("Price");


            //check for if device exist for saving
            if (orderViewModelList.Count() > 0)
            {
                //Convert to csv class type
                int i = 0;
                foreach (var item in orderViewModelList)
                {
                    HSSFRow enqRow = sheet1.CreateRow(i + 1);

                    enqRow.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(item.OrderId);

                    enqRow.CreateCell(5).SetCellValue(( item.OrderAmount));
                    i++;
                }
            }

            MemoryStream file = new MemoryStream();
            hssfworkbook.Write(file);

            byte[] Data = file.GetBuffer();
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=OrderReport.xls");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            Response.BinaryWrite(Data);
            Response.End();
```

See [this example](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Create-Excel-Spreadsheets-Using-NPOI.aspx) also

If you want to append a new sheet to existing excel sheet **[refer this example](http://www.zachhunter.com/2010/05/npoi-excel-template/)**

Comment: @SigridAnnOmila See the sample code for creating excel. If you want to use the existing file and add one more sheet to it, refer the last link